# select from 2 tables with for statement in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have 2 table and want to select data from them

```
table 1 :
id
name

table 2
id
name
table1.id
```

and i want a query to make this resualt:

```
table1.id
table1.name
count(table2.id)
```

this is simple and solved by this way :

```
SELECT 
c.id as corridor_id,
c.name as corridor_name,
(SELECT COUNT( r.id ) FROM rooms AS r WHERE r.corridorid = c.id ) as room_count
FROM corridors AS c
```

now if i add another table like this :

```
table3
id
name
table2.id
```

and want a query like this :

```
table1.id
table1.name
count(table2.id)
count(table3.id)
```

idk how can i do such as this query, but if there is a way i'll be happy to find it, many tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need nested `SELECT` statement here. You can do it by grouping and to avoid double-counting you would want `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT 
    c.id as corridor_id,
    c.name as corridor_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT r1.id),
    COUNT(DISTINCT r2.id)
FROM 
    corridors c
    JOIN rooms r ON r.corridorid = c.id
    JOIN rooms2 r2 ON r2.corridorid = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

If you want to properly treat missing values (0 counts) you can also do this:

```
SELECT 
    c.id as corridor_id,
    c.name as corridor_name,
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT r1.id), 0),
    IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT r2.id), 0)
FROM 
    corridors c
    LEFT JOIN rooms r ON r.corridorid = c.id
    LEFT JOIN rooms2 r2 ON r2.corridorid = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to join them all together, and then Group them along these lines:

```
SELECT 
   t1.Id,
   t1.Name,
   Count(t2.Id) AS T2Count,
   Count(t3.Id) AS T3Count 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.Id = t2.table1_id
JOIN table3 t3
ON t2.id = t3.table2_id
GROUP BY t1.Id, t1.Name
```